# How do I get the value from a class property in Objective-C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, reflection

I want to get variable value from an objective-c class, using reflection.

company.h looks like

```
@interface Company : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* phone;
- (NSString*) getPropertyValueByName: (NSString*) paramName;
```

company.m looks like

```
@implementation Company
@synthesize phone;
- (NSString*) getPropertyValueByName: (NSString*) paramName
{    
    id me = self;
    value = [me objectForKey: paramName];
    return value;
}
@end
```

I am using this like:

```
Company* comp = [Company new];
comp.phone = @"+30123456";

NSString* phone = comp.getPropertyValueByName(@"phone");
```

What I am getting is an exception:

```
-[Company objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Comment: I have rolled back the question to the original version because otherwise the answer you accepted makes no sense otherwise.  In fact, I nearly down voted it because it appeared to make such little sense.

Comment: @JeremyP apparently people like this question. anyway..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That should be valueForKey instead of objectForKey. objectForKey is an NSDictionary instance method.
 Besides that there's a potentional mistake in your code. Your return type in the above method is string but you don't cast it to NSString before returning.Even if you're sure that it'll always return a string it's good practice to avoid any doubts. And when declaring an NSString property you should copy it rather than retaining it. And, what's the point in declaring a "me" variable if you can easily say:

```
[self valueForkey:paramName];
```

Comment: There's no point in casting the value you are about to return from id to string. It doesn't suppress any warnings and it doesn't make any difference at all at run time.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I did not notice that the property for the key was of type string.Thank you you Jeremy for correcting my mistake.

Answer (score 10):

There is a much easier way to do it by using [Key-Value-Coding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000107i).

There is already a way to get the value of a property by passing a string:

```
-(id)valueForKey:(NSString *)keyName;
```

You don't need to write your own methods for this.

Comment: Link is dead, seems like this is the new link? https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html